# MySQL Concurrent INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IF

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

My SQL statement can be simplified to something similar as follow:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (RUNNING_NO, A, B)
(SELECT RUN_ID, C, D FROM `TABLE2` WHERE ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
RUNNING_NO = IF(RUNNING_NO > RUN_ID, RUNNING_NO, RUN_ID)
, A = IF(RUNNING_NO > RUN_ID, A, C)
, B = IF(RUNNING_NO > RUN_ID, B, D);
```

where I want to replace the row only if the RUN_ID from TABLE2 are larger than the one in the TABLE1. I will have several sessions with different WHERE condition that will run this statement concurrently and they might return the same C values with different RUN_ID.

TABLE1 primary key is A while in TABLE2 primary key is RUN_ID + C.

I am using InnoDB engine.

Does the database lock the RUNNING_ID that was checked to the latest value of the record (I am afraid the value was updated by another session that was with a higher RUN_ID than the original one in the TABLE1 as well as the current RUN_ID from TABLE2)? If it does, is there any source of documents that mentioned this?

------------------------- [Edited - sample data]

```
TABLE1
RUNNING_ID  |  A   |  B
10             AA    Apple

TABLE2
RUN_ID      |  C   |  D
11 ....
20             AA    Orange
21 ....
30             AA    Melon
```

Two sessions are running

Session A took the records from 11 to 20,
Session B took the records from 21 to 30,
Session B completed the insert select first (which means the TABLE1 is updated to 30)

Could the Session A still does the comparison with the RUNNING_ID 10?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: *TABLE1 primary key is A* ... and you need to change PK value? I think there is something wrong with your DB structure...

Comment: Oh right, I actually didn't notice that, thanks! But my main point was to replace the B with the latest running id